# Converting Creo files to STP on linux

Tags: cad

I need to send out some PRT files for tooling that have been made using Creo. I do not have a windows PC or mac available at the moment, only linux. Does anyone have some advice how to go from here?

Comment: Well, telling us what format they are in at the moment and what format they need to be in would help...

Comment: Added: PRT>STP  conversion

Comment: There are some comercial tools for linux (like [coretechnologie](https://www.coretechnologie.com/)) that can do this but no free or open source ones as far as im aware. Would something you have to pay for suffice?

Comment: Preferred not but if feature rich enough and not too expensive

Comment: I can't seem to be able to figure out how to purchase this software you mention @joojaa

Comment: You need to call them, its sort of industrial service type software so they dont exactly have a price. But instead you pay based on how you want to use it. Their main goal is for you to embed it into your software then take a cut. Though they also have conversion tool as a example.

Comment: have you looked for online (web page) converters?

Comment: "PRT is a proprietary file format used by Pro Engineer, now named Creo. DWG is a proprietary file format from Autodesk. Proprietary file formats are usually undisclosed. The commercial CAD applications can usually open file formats from competitors by reverse engineering the file format in-house, or licensing a third-party file import library. The open source projects do not have the resources to do the former and evidently by their nature cannot do the latter." https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2163088